# Error while calling FETCH API

Tags: typescript, react-native, visual-studio-code

I am getting below error while compiling typescript code.

> Error:
>
> Argument of type '{ method: string; headers: { 'Accept': string; 'Content-Type': string; 'Authorization': string; }...' is not assignable to parameter of type 'RequestInit'.
>     Types of property 'headers' are incompatible.
>       Type '{ 'Accept': string; 'Content-Type': string; 'Authorization': string; }' is not assignable to type 'Headers | string[][]'.
>         Object literal may only specify known properties, and ''Accept'' does not exist in type 'Headers | string[][]'.
>   The terminal process terminated with exit code: 1

```
fetch(URL, {
                method: 'GET',
                headers: {
                    'Accept': 'application/json',
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                    'Authorization': "Bearer " + token
                }
            })
            .then((responseJson) => {

                return responseJson;
            })
            .catch((error) => {

                console.error(error);
            });


"dependencies": {
    "expo": "^21.0.2",
    "jquery": "^3.2.1",
    "lodash": "^4.17.4",
    "mobx": "^3.2.2",
    "mobx-react": "^4.2.2",
    "moment": "^2.19.1",
    "react": "16.0.0-alpha.12",
    "react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-21.0.2.tar.gz",
    "react-native-azure-ad": "^0.2.4",
    "react-native-sqlite-2": "^1.5.0",
    "react-native-sqlite-storage": "^3.3.3",
    "react-native-tabs": "^1.0.9",
    "typescript": "^2.5.3"
  }
```

Comment: [It's a known recent bug in lib.dom.d.ts](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/19658), affecting TypeScript 2.6 I believe

Comment: Visual studio code update solved the issue for me